# Changing page orientation of Jasper report in Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using *.jasper report generated with iReport in Java program. I need to change report orientation programmatically. Here is my code:

```
final File template = new File("report.jasper");
final JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(template);
//connection is defined previously
final JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, metadata, connection);
//reprot.jasper is defined with LANDSCAPE orientation
print.setOrientation(OrientationEnum.PORTRAIT);
```

The last line has no effect on neither generated pdf or on-screen component.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the orientation on the JasperPrint object does not change the width or height of the generated pages. 
I think you need to change the page orientation before report filling.

Some more [details](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/527518/setting-page-orientation-runtime)

Comment: How do you change the page orientation? More detail here, please.

Comment: @vikingsteve please check the link, the last comment has all details